# Working with modals, HTML not getting JS file in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-components

I am creating a gallery website for a photographer, but I have an issue with the gallery itself.

I want to be able to click on an image and open a modal where I can see all pictures in the gallery by clicking next and previous.
My problem is that my HTML does not recognise the JS file and does not read it. Even if I put it inside `<script></script>` tag inside the HTML file.

Does anyone have a solution?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">{{title}}</h1>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="This is my title" data-caption="Some lovely red flowers" data-image="http://onelive.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/flower-delivery-online.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://process.filestackapi.com/A1zigIk7qS7GZogv9QlQGz/resize=w:700/compress/GHTpGIeyTxausxCJYMyR" alt="Short alt text">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="The car i dream about" data-caption="If you sponsor me, I can drive this car" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://process.filestackapi.com/A1zigIk7qS7GZogv9QlQGz/resize=w:700/compress/GHTpGIeyTxausxCJYMyR" alt="A alt text">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="Im so nice" data-caption="And if there is money left, my girlfriend will receive this car" data-image="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/1997_Fiat_Panda.JPG" data-target="#image-gallery">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://process.filestackapi.com/A1zigIk7qS7GZogv9QlQGz/resize=w:700/compress/GHTpGIeyTxausxCJYMyR" alt="Another alt text">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">
              This text will be overwritten by jQuery
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src="js/openModal.js"></script>
```

And JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  loadGallery(true, 'a.thumbnail');

  //This function disables buttons when needed
  function disableButtons(counter_max, counter_current){
    $('#show-previous-image, #show-next-image').show();
    if(counter_max == counter_current){
      $('#show-next-image').hide();
    } else if (counter_current == 1){
      $('#show-previous-image').hide();
    }
  }

  /**
     *
     * @param setIDs        Sets IDs when DOM is loaded. If using a PHP counter, set to false.
     * @param setClickAttr  Sets the attribute for the click handler.
     */

  function loadGallery(setIDs, setClickAttr){
    var current_image,
        selector,
        counter = 0;

    $('#show-next-image, #show-previous-image').click(function(){
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'show-previous-image'){
        current_image--;
      } else {
        current_image++;
      }

      selector = $('[data-image-id="' + current_image + '"]');
      updateGallery(selector);
    });

    function updateGallery(selector) {
      var $sel = selector;
      current_image = $sel.data('image-id');
      $('#image-gallery-caption').text($sel.data('caption'));
      $('#image-gallery-title').text($sel.data('title'));
      $('#image-gallery-image').attr('src', $sel.data('image'));
      disableButtons(counter, $sel.data('image-id'));
    }

    if(setIDs == true){
      $('[data-image-id]').each(function(){
        counter++;
        $(this).attr('data-image-id',counter);
      });
    }
    $(setClickAttr).on('click',function(){
      updateGallery($(this));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: People would be able to help you even more if you put all this code in jsfiddle/codepen etc.

Comment: Error in console? [How to open the JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I get no error in the console. On click, I open the a modal, but the image does not show. 
When looking at the sources in the console I can see that the src of the image was not given to the js file.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette , okay, so how would I make it work? 
This is the first time I am working with modals and jquery to be honest and I am not sure what I am doing here...

Comment: It looks like your code is working in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/awNLqV?editors=1011)... but this image URL fails : http://onelive.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/flower-delivery-online.jpg. It fails on direct access...

Comment: http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg also fails... Ending in a consumer survey... So just provide valid URLs in `data-image` ;)

Comment: Here is the same [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qjZVKz?editors=1111) using valid `img` URLs. *(And a little CSS to contain them inside the modal)*

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is about providing valid `img` URLs in `data-image`.

Your code is working. [Here it is using valid kittens pics URL](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qjZVKz?editors=1111).

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="The car i dream about" data-caption="If you sponsor me, I can drive this car" data-image="[PROVIDE VALID URL HERE]" data-target="#image-gallery">
```

I also added this CSS to "contain" the images within the modal:

```
#image-gallery-image{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense now.
Just one more thing.. I am using filestack to host my pictures, is it not compatible with modals? What other way might I be able to get the images from there but the link provided?

Comment: Use the "share" link or... They seem to call it the "Deliver" link. It should look like this one : https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/Isd5CbqhS9GbRgVYECQj

Comment: If you can open the link in a browser and view your pic (and your pic only). It's the right one.

Comment: For some reason it is not working. Might I not be connecting to the javascript file at all? 
When I integrated your solution into my application it did not show the images.

Comment: *«For some reason... »* can be anything. What do you expect me to answer that? Do you have a live link to your page?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, have not gotten the domain yet. 
What I am asking is, if I use a <script> tag into my html and put the jquery code in there, do I need to import any scripts for it to work?
Right now I am trying to get it from a different folder in my project, and I don't think it is getting it. 
I saw the code you posted on code pen and it is working as it is, but as soon as I get it into my html file it does not show the image.

Comment: Well... Look at the CodePen's settings. There is in button for it, which opens a "modal" (lollll). You see a menu. Look at CSS and JavaScript external libraries loaded to make it work.